# How open acticity in Flutter when open push notification set a WebView and set given link in notiification body?

Tags: flutter, android-webview, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am using Firebase push Notification. Now I need a WebView when the user opens a push notification, and that time (onMessageOpenedApp) I need to open WebView using a link inside notification body part (with this link open WebView).

How to set a new activity or set WebView on this method (onMessageOpenedApp) inside flutter?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code you have done

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
  print(message.data);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      message.data.hashCode,
      message.data['title'],
      message.data['body'],
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channel.description,
        ),
      ));
}


const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
  importance: Importance.high,
);



final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  runApp(HomePage());
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _url = 'https://www.*********.com/';
  bool isLoading=true;
  static const orange = const Color(0xffFF6C23);

  // late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;
  //
  // PushNotification _notificationInfo = PushNotification();
  //
  // void registerNotification() async {
  //
  //   await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //   _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  //   FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  //
  //   NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
  //     alert: true,
  //     badge: true,
  //     provisional: false,
  //     sound: true,
  //   );
  //   FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
  //
  //    // print('Message clicked!');
  //     PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
  //       priority: ' ',
  //       title: message.notification?.title,
  //       body: message.notification?.body,
  //       dataTitle: message.data['title'],
  //       dataBody: message.data['body'],
  //     );
  //     setState(() {
  //       _notificationInfo = notification;
  //
  //     //  _url = 'https://facebook.com';
  //
  //     });
  //
  //     //_url = 'https://facebook.com';
  //   });
  //
  // }
  //
  //
  // checkForInitialMessage() async {
  //   await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //   RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
  //   await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  //
  //
  //   if (initialMessage != null) {
  //     PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
  //       title: initialMessage.notification?.title,
  //       body: initialMessage.notification?.body,
  //       dataTitle: initialMessage.data['title'],
  //       dataBody: initialMessage.data['body'],
  //     );
  //
  //     setState(() {
  //       _notificationInfo = notification;
  //
  //     });
  //   }
  // }
  late String token;
  List subscribed = [];
  @override
  void initState() {

    var initialzationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/appstore');
    var initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(android: initialzationSettingsAndroid);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: android.smallIcon,
              ),
            ));
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!${channel.name}');
      print('BODY DATA IS HER !${message.data['body']}');
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
              (route) => false);

    });
    getToken();
    //getTopics();

    // registerNotification();
    // checkForInitialMessage();
    //
    // // For handling notification when the app is in background
    // // but not terminated
    // FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    //   PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
    //     title: message.notification?.title,
    //     body: message.notification?.body,
    //     dataTitle: message.data['title'],
    //     dataBody: message.data['body'],
    //   );
    //   setState(() {
    //     _notificationInfo = notification;
    //   });
    // });

    super.initState();
  }
  getToken() async {
    token = (await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken())!;
    setState(() {
      token = token;
    });
    print(token);
  }
  //
  // getTopics() async {
  //   await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  //       .collection('topics')
  //       .get()
  //       .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
  //     if (token == element.id) {
  //       subscribed = element.data().keys.toList();
  //     }
  //   }));
  //
  //   setState(() {
  //     subscribed = subscribed;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              WebView(
                 javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialUrl: _url,
                onPageFinished: (finish) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
              ),
              isLoading ?
              Center( child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: orange),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Text('Loading', style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                  ))
                ],
              ),)
                  : Stack(),
            ],
          ),

        )

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).